# Second price in WooCommerce variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have added second price for variable products with this code and it works just fine.

```
// Backend Variation - Add / Display MRSP Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_variation_options_pricing_msrp', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_pricing_msrp( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_msrp_'.$loop,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
        'class' => 'short wc_input_price',
        'label' => __( 'Цена за комплект', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'value' => wc_format_localized_price( get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_msrp', true ) ),
        'data_type' => 'price',
    ) );
}

// Backend Variation - Save MRSP Field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_pricing_msrp',10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_pricing_msrp( $variation_id, $loop ){
    if( isset($_POST['_msrp_'.$loop]) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_msrp', wc_clean( wp_unslash( str_replace( ',', '.', $_POST['_msrp_'.$loop] ) ) ) );
}

// Frontend Variation - MRSP display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">' . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) .
        '<span class="msrp-price">' . wc_price( $msrp ) . '</span></div>' . $data['price_html'];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

On frontend it looks like this (when colour is selected):

This is how it looks on frontend

[image: img]

Now we need a little modification and I dont know how to do it:

1. I need to add small text before price (on screenshot its 87.18p.) The same as it is on the top price.
2. I need to move top price to bottom and to move bottom price to top.

I believe that I need to add some code (similar to this):

```
// Frontend Variation - MRSP display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">' . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) .
        '<span class="msrp-price">' . wc_price( $msrp ) . '</span></div>' . $data['price_html'];
    }

    return $data;
```

But I'm not a programmer...
I would appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firs since your not a programmer I explane whats happening using command lines in your the code:

```php
// Frontend Variation - MRSP display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '
        <div class="woocommerce_msrp">' //wrapper box
        . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) //This is a wil prinnt a label with the text 'Комплект'
        .'<span class="msrp-price">' // html label
        . wc_price( $msrp )// your new price 
        . '</span>'//end html label 
        .'</div>' //end wrapper
        . $data['price_html']; // default price of product
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Then for adding a symbol before your price you simply add the sybol to the `span`, like this:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '
        <div class="woocommerce_msrp">' //wrapper box
        . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) //This is a wil prinnt a label with the text 'Комплект'
        .'<span class="msrp-price"> ------SYMBOL HERE----- ' // html label and symbol
        . wc_price( $msrp )// your new price 
        . '</span>'//end html label 
        .'</div>' //end wrapper
        . $data['price_html']; // default price of product
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Then finaly switching the prices is done by switching them in the code. So your finel product will look like this:

```php
// Frontend Variation - MRSP display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_msrp', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_msrp( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $msrp = $variation->get_meta('_msrp') ) {
        $data['price_html'] = 
        $data['price_html'] // default price of product
        .'<div class="woocommerce_msrp">' //wrapper box
        . __( 'Комплект: ', 'woocommerce' ) //This is a wil prinnt a label with the text 'Комплект'
        .'<span class="msrp-price">  ------SYMBOL HERE----- ' // html label and symbol
        . wc_price( $msrp )// your new price 
        . '</span>'//end html label 
        .'</div>'; //end wrapper
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Hope this wil help you and understand what's going on :-) !

Comment: Thank you @Tim567. I got half of my task done....prices switched, but label appeared NOT before first price.You can see it here https://elporta.vgdesign.by/shop/mezhkomnatnye-dveri/jeko-shpon/legno-38/ when selecting a color...I need that label to go before top price.